# Using LINQ in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have following normal **foreach** using LINQ query, How can i transform it using **Parallel.Foreach**

```
foreach (var i in media.Where(x => x is Video)
{
    this.Update(i);
}
```

How can i do it like

```
Parallel.ForEach(media,i =>
{
    //LINQ
});
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened? How was that different from what you wanted to happen? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The documentation goes into significant detail regarding the "how to do X", so you start there, and if you have problems, post a _specific_ question detailing the above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first argument to `Parallel.ForEach` is an enumerable, so the obvious way would be:

```
Parallel.ForEach(media.Where(x => x is Video).OrderBy(x => x.Contains("a")), i =>
{
    //this.Update(i);
    // commented out because you'll probably want to Invoke it
    // depending on what it does exactly.

});
```

Comment: It says NoOverload method foreach take 1 arguments

Comment: That's 2 arguments, the enumerable and the action.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, `Where(x => x is Video)` can be replaced by `OfType<Video>()`.
Second, for fluent syntax it's better to use `ParallelEnumerable.ForAll` extension method:

```
media.OfType<Video>()
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(this.Update)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do either

```
Parallel.ForEach(media.Where(x => x is Video), this.Update);
```

or

```
media.AsParallel().Where(x => x is Video).ForAll(this.Update);
```

Adding an order in a parallel process makes no sense here.

Comment: Well order isn't there

Comment: You had OrderBy in your question.

Comment: Yeah that was just for demo, Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Parallel.ForEach<Video>(media.Where(x => x is Video), i =>
{
    this.Update(i);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... basically like you've said ... but ... keep in mind that if you need to order the results and you're acting on that, it's not really parallel ...

The linq parallel foreach will partition your collection and work on it at the same time, which you also need to take into account making sure your `this.Update` can work with multiple users without messing up .

So, what's the question really ?